# Send AIX local7 logs to separate file

Tags: aix, syslog

We have an AIX 7.1 system that is being flooded with log entries from the `local7` facility. Specifically, `local7.err`.

I don't know what I did this time around but the `local7.err` entries are now being sent to the `/var/adm/ras/wap.log` file that I defined.

Now my question is: How do I stop them from going to `/var/adm/ras/syslog.caa` as well? It appears they are going to both locations instead of just the one.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Had to explicitly configure each of the other facilities excluding the `local7`:

```
kern,user,mail,daemon,auth,syslog,lpr,news,uucp.info /var/adm/ras/syslog.caa rotate time 10m files 10 compress
```

Some can probably be removed (`news, uucp`).

Comment: If you were starting from *, I think you can say something like *,!local7 -- to be shorter

Comment: From what I can see that is something that is available in syslog-ng. It doesn't look like we're running that. Rather, we're just running POS (Plain-Old Syslog).